# mysql stored procedure dynamic if else block like eval

Tags: mysql

This is a simple working example

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    IF(invar = 1) THEN
        SET outvar = 'ok';
    END IF;
END;
```

But is it possible to do something like this to work in mysql?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    
    SET @vs_query = CONCAT(
        "IF(invar = 1)",
        "SET outvar = 'ok';",
        "END IF;"
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @vs_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
END;
```

Something like EVAL @vs_query string in mysql ?

Comment: Did you get any exception? If so, can you please share them?

Comment: No. Any exception ... Succesful execution but return nothing. Expected outvar = ok